# How to calculate mean of previous values of other firms for Director ID before he joins the firm

Tags: loops, stata, mean

I need to calculate the previous wage of director before he joins a new company.

I have created a simple dataset for one director (in practice I have many observations of director_id). This director with ID = 1 manages 5 firms which he joined in different years (the variable called enter). If director joined firm number 2 in 2011, I need the average of the variable wage for all years before 2011 which he was managing. For the same director = 1, I need a different mean(wage) for firm number 3 which he joined in 2012 (which will include mean(wage) from previous 2 companies that he managed before entering company 3 in 2012).

Below is the data. I would really appreciate your help in coding this problem.

```
clear

input enter year wage director_id firm_id
2006 2006 6.4790964 1 1
2006 2010 6.4783854 1 1
2006 2011 6.4067149 1 1
2006 2012 6.3716507 1 1
2006 2013 6.2248578 1 1
2006 2014 6.0631728 1 1
2011 2011 5.0127039 1 2
2011 2012 4.9616795 1 2
2011 2013 4.9483747 1 2
2011 2014 5.2612371 1 2
2012 2012 4.5389338 1 3
2012 2013 4.4322848 1 3
2012 2014 4.3223209 1 3
2013 2013 4.336947 1 4
2013 2014 4.27459 1 4
2015 2015 -.60586482 1 5
2015 2016 .085194588 1 5
end
```

I just need to exclude from mean(wage) all values that happen after he enters, so really need to regard only years before he enters a new company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recipe for what I think you seek is that the mean previous wage in other firms =

(SUM of previous wages in all firms MINUS sum of previous wages in this firm) / (COUNT of previous years in all firms MINUS count of previous years in this firm).

Your example is helpful but the `wage` variable is too irregular to allow easy eyeball checks.

Consider this sequence, where `rangestat` is from SSC.

```
clear

input enter year wage director_id firm_id
2006 2006 6.4790964 1 1
2006 2010 6.4783854 1 1
2006 2011 6.4067149 1 1
2006 2012 6.3716507 1 1
2006 2013 6.2248578 1 1
2006 2014 6.0631728 1 1
2011 2011 5.0127039 1 2
2011 2012 4.9616795 1 2
2011 2013 4.9483747 1 2
2011 2014 5.2612371 1 2
2012 2012 4.5389338 1 3
2012 2013 4.4322848 1 3
2012 2014 4.3223209 1 3
2013 2013 4.336947 1 4
2013 2014 4.27459 1 4
2015 2015 -.60586482 1 5
2015 2016 .085194588 1 5
end

sort year firm_id 
replace wage = _n 

rangestat (sum) SUM=wage (count) COUNT=wage, int(year . -1) by(director_id) 

rangestat (sum) sum=wage (count) count=wage, int(year . -1) by(director_id firm_id) 

replace sum = 0 if sum == . 
replace count = 0 if count == . 
gen wanted = (SUM - sum) / (COUNT - count)  

list, sepby(year)

    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | enter   year   wage   direct~d   firm_id   SUM   COUNT   sum   count     wanted |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |  2006   2006      1          1         1     .       .     0       0          . |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  2. |  2006   2010      2          1         1     1       1     1       1          . |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  3. |  2006   2011      3          1         1     3       2     3       2          . |
  4. |  2011   2011      4          1         2     3       2     0       0        1.5 |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  5. |  2006   2012      5          1         1    10       4     6       3          4 |
  6. |  2011   2012      6          1         2    10       4     4       1          2 |
  7. |  2012   2012      7          1         3    10       4     0       0        2.5 |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  8. |  2006   2013      8          1         1    28       7    11       4   5.666667 |
  9. |  2011   2013      9          1         2    28       7    10       2        3.6 |
 10. |  2012   2013     10          1         3    28       7     7       1        3.5 |
 11. |  2013   2013     11          1         4    28       7     0       0          4 |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 12. |  2006   2014     12          1         1    66      11    19       5   7.833333 |
 13. |  2011   2014     13          1         2    66      11    19       3      5.875 |
 14. |  2012   2014     14          1         3    66      11    17       2   5.444445 |
 15. |  2013   2014     15          1         4    66      11    11       1        5.5 |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 16. |  2015   2015     16          1         5   120      15     0       0          8 |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 17. |  2015   2016     17          1         5   136      16    16       1          8 |
     +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I need. When keeping observations where enter=year, I have the previous wage from all other firms. Sorry about the commas in Stata. Is it also possible to calculate not the whole history of wage but rather just considering 3 previous years before he enters?

Comment: Indeed. See the `help` for `rangestat`.